# For $a,b \in \mathbb {F}_{{2^n}}$, $n$ is odd; $a^2+b^2+ab=0$ implies that $a=b=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Let $a,b$ be two elements of the finite field $\mathbb {F}_{{2^n}}$, where $n$ is odd. If $a^2+b^2+ab=0$ then I have to show that $a=b=0$.

Enough to show at least one of $a,b\in \mathbb F_2$. If $a\in \mathbb F_2$ then $b$ satisfy a polynomial of degree at most $2$. Since $n$ is odd, $b$ must also be in $\mathbb F_2$. If none of $a,b$ is in $\mathbb F_2$ I can't draw a contradiction. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b\ne 0$ then let $x= a/b$ and now we have $$x^2+x+1=0\implies x^3=1$$

Since $x^{2^n-1}=1$ and $\gcd (3,2^n-1)=1$ we have $x=1$ so $a=b$. But then $3a^2=0$ and thus $a=0$

---

$\gcd (3,2^n-1)=1$ since: $$2^n-1 \equiv_3 (-1)^n-1 \equiv_3 1\implies 3\nmid 2^n-1$$

Comment: How to show $\gcd(3,2^n-1)=1$ for $n$ odd?

Comment: @user371231 Note $2^{2k+1}=4^k\cdot 2\equiv 1^k\cdot 2=2\not\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Comment: I add that in my post@richrow

Comment: Alternatively, since $t^2+t+1\in\mathbb F_2[t]$ is irreducible, conclude that $2 = [\mathbb F_2(x):\mathbb F_2] | n$.